# Google Play Services Ads?

Tags: android-gradle-plugin, admob, google-play-services, build.gradle, jcenter

I cant add android studio App Admob to an app.

grandle Could not download this

'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/gms/google-services/3.1.1/google-services-3.1.1.pom'.

Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/gms/google-services/3.1.1/google-services-3.1.1.pom'.

```
Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'


    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
}

 task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
 }
```

[SCREENSHOTS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vdKOv.jpg)

[SCREENSHOTS1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rtAZX.jpg)

[SCREENSHOTS2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z42lz.jpg)

[SCREENSHOTS3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IPIl1.jpg)

[SCREENSHOTS4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T7Mrk.jpg)

[SCREENSHOTS5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1rsCV.jpg)

Comment: @hulio you add play-services-gcm in your gradle file? pleace add your gradle files as code so we can help you and i will suggest you to put code not post picture

Comment: Thx for your reply..
where can i get code of my "gradle files" ? ..

Comment: gradle scripts project and app, is 2 files with green circle like one in screenshots5 project:admob

Comment: Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'
        

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

Comment: @hulio try my answer and if doesnt work please post in your question the other gradle too

Comment: thanks for your answer but same issue .. gradle cant DOWNLOAD those two files. .... 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/gms/google-services/4.0.1/google-services-4.0.1.pom' ............. AND ALSO THAT ONE ......"'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/gms/google-services/4.0.1/google-services-4.0.1.pom' ..............@ParaskevasNtsounos